# In Google Sheets, how can I copy a cell's reference, to paste ='sheet2'!E15 into a cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets - one where I'm computing stuff, and one where I'm presenting the results. I'd prefer to keep all the computation on the one sheet, and just refer to the results in the other - makes it easier to check.

I know I can type = and then start moving around with the cursor keys, click the other sheet's tab at the bottom, and then choose a cell there to end up with this cell referring to the other cell with something like `='sheet2'!E15` but steering the box around is tedious.

Can I have the sheets open in two separate windows and copy the cell from one window and do some sort of 'paste special: reference to cell' where I want `='sheet2'!E15` to be put into the other cell (not just the value or the formula)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can I have the sheets open in two separate windows and copy the cell from one window and do some sort of 'paste special: reference to cell' where I want ='sheet2'!E15 to be put into the other cell (not just the value or the formula)?*

No.

I agree that moving the cursor around can be tedious, but this is the way that Google Sheets works. The same is true for Excel, and every other spreadsheet that I'm familiar with.

Comment: Bugger. But thanks. :)